# How to copy string value from Form2 to Form1 label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form1 that has a toolStripStatusLabel. Then Form2 that has button and is there string with value ( Hello ). I need if i click on the button, show value "Hello" to toolStripStatusLabel in Form1. toolStripStatusLabel is set to public.
This show me :

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel'*

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
    public form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form1 form = new Form1();
    string example = "hello";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.toolStripLabel1 = example;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You try to mean `form.toolStripLabel1.Text = example;` or something?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, but button do not write hello to toolstrip

Answer (score 0):

You should you:

```
form.toolStripLabel1.Text = example;
```

instead of:

```
form.toolStripLabel1 = example;
```

And you might want to take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms
If you want to share data between 2 forms

Comment: You are right, but button do not write hello to toolstrip

Comment: @Lukas I changed my answer, this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Text property in the ToolStripLabel object.

```
form.toolStripLabel1.Text = example;
```

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You are right, but button do not write hello to toolstrip

Comment: You have to replace "Some text" with whatever you want to be written in there. In this case, example variable.

Comment: Oh, i dont know exactly how. Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd need to say `formtoolStripLabel1.Text = example;` rather than what you said. However, this will not affect the one from the original instance of Form1. If you wanted to affect the original instance of Form1, you'd make the tooStripLabel `public static` rather than just `public` so that all classes can affect it immediately.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, but button do not write hello to toolstrip

Comment: add `public delegate void StringChange(string newstring);` outside the class. Then inside the class I would add `public StringChange StringChange` and then in the button_Click function I would put `StringChange(example);`. So I'm assuming you're opening Form2 from inside Form1. In which case you'd put `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` `form2.StringChange += new StringChange(ChangeFunction);` `form2.ShowDialog();` and finally create a void: `private void ChangeFunction(string input) { formtoolStripLabel1.Text = input;}`

Comment: Sorry if that's a bit messy.

Comment: Thank you for help, i try it. Its new for me and is not easy.

Comment: Yeah, stuff like this'll become second nature if you keep making projects like you seem to be doing.